# Unexpected behavior with OrderBy [ Descending ]() and SkipWhile()

Tags: c#, linq

I'm seeing some behavior that I'm having a hard time understanding. Given a list of `DateTime`s, I want to only select dates which occur in past year, in descending order. But using `OrderBy()`, `OrderByDescending()`, and `SkipWhile()` is acting.....strange. Given a list starting from today, including the last 100 months like such:

```
List<DateTime> ldt = new List<DateTime>();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    ldt.Add(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-i));
}
```

I started with the following code:

```
ldt = ldt.OrderByDescending(date => date).
          SkipWhile(date => date <= DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1)).ToList();
```

This orders the list properly, but doesn't skip any of the records. So for fun, I tried this (skipping everything earlier than today, i.e., everything):

```
 ldt = ldt.OrderByDescending(date => date).
            SkipWhile(date => date <= DateTime.Now).ToList();
```

Which *works*. The list is empty. Then I tried the following (OrderBy instead of OrderByDescending) :

```
ldt = ldt.OrderBy(date => date).
          SkipWhile(date => date <= DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1)).ToList();
```

Which works exactly as expected - the list is ordered, and the dates are properly filtered. So the end result, which works, is:

```
ldt = ldt.OrderBy(date => date).
          SkipWhile(date => date <= DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1)).ToList();
ldt = ldt.OrderByDescending(date => date).ToList();
```

Skipping, then re-ordering. So what am I missing? Why do some of these work, and some break in unpredictable ways? What's the *proper* one line command for what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to only select dates which occur in past year

Instead of using `SkipWhile`, you should be able to use `.Where`:

```
 ldt = ldt.Where(date => date.> DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1))
        .OrderByDescending(date => date).ToList();
```

Comment: .Where() forces the evaluation of the entire list. Since he also needs to sort, that's slower :)

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Yes, but it also doesn't require the input list to be sorted in advance.  Not sure if that's guaranteed or not.  (His example, of course, works with TakeWhile)

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: `Where` will only force it lazily. This way there's less to sort - only the entries which *need* to be sorted (because they're included) will be. If you use `OrderByDescending` followed by `TakeWhile` (as per my answer) that will sort *everything* and then find out what needs to be kept. Fewer invocations of the predicate, but more sorting.

Comment: @JonSkeet Since we're calling .ToList here there's nothing lazy about it. But good point that it might be faster to filter before sorting.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: So there's nothing lazy about it either way - I don't see the point of your first comment, unless you were pointing out that the predicate will be applied to more items (which is true).

Answer (score 6):

Basically, you want [`TakeWhile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534804.aspx) instead of `SkipWhile`:

```
ldt = ldt.OrderByDescending(date => date)
         .TakeWhile(date => date > DateTime.Now)
         .ToList();
```

After you've used `OrderByDescending`, the entries you want to keep are the *first* ones... whereas `SkipWhile` assumes you want to discard some entries, and then *keep* the rest.

(Or you could filter using `Where` and then sort, as Reed suggests. Both will work Reed's may be more efficient. Use whichever you find simpler to understand.)

When you're puzzled by something like this, it's sometimes worth writing out an example of the data on a piece of paper. Work out what the sequence looks like after each step, and then what the next step would do.